# Laravel 5: Using Cache:: or DB:: within the Console Kernel's schedule() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to run an Artisan console command in Laravel 5 at varying, user-configured time intervals. I have built the console command and have a database (with Eloquent model) holding a "run frequency" configuration value.

Within the `schedule()` function of `App\Console\Kernel.php` I'd like to pull this value out of the database and run the command as and when needed based on this value.

I receive a `Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found` when using `DB::table()...` with or without `use DB;`, and the same happens if I try to use `Cache::...` functions too.

I'm assuming the IoC container isn't accessible from within the `schedule()` function of `App\Console\Kernel.php` file. Has anyone had similar and found an elegant workaround?

My simplified code is:

```
<?php namespace App\Console;

use Cache;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $settings = Cache::get('settings');
    }
```

and the error:

```
php artisan schedule:run
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cache' not found in /home/vagrant/projects/project/dir/api/app/Console/Kernel.php on line 26
```

any help would be greatfully appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache as Cache;`?

Comment: yeah no joy with that, the error that gives is

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on null`

I've also tried $this->app->make('cache') etc but no joy

Comment: That's odd, Cache should be available, I think. Sorry if I bother you, but something like `$cache = new Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache();` doesn't work either?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but same outcome I'm afraid. You gave me the idea to try `$cache = new \Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager($this->app);` which works as much as to setup the CacheManager, but then I receive `ReflectionException`'s for `config` so I think the app / IoC just isn't there at this stage of the app

Comment: Cache is in the global namespace, have you tried using `$settings = \Cache::get('settings');` ?

Comment: I have, that also gives the `Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed by Taylor in 5.0.21 ([Git Commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/6a9aa29278e13274549d8205f2b21a2d2cb70e98)) so anyone experiencing the same issue can run `composer update` to get the latest version of the framework which will allow you to use

`Use DB;`

`Use Cache;`

etc as usual