# Laravel custom artisan command and php extension GnuPG not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gnupg, php-extension

I am making my own command in Laravel and from my Command class I call controller method. Like this:

```
public function fire(\BankEmailController $bankEmailController)
{
    if($this->option('fetch')){
       $this->userInformResluts($bankEmailController->checkEmails());
    }
}
```

In checkEmails method I create new GnuPG class:

```
putenv('GNUPGHOME=/var/www/mbiuro/panel/.gnupg');
$gpg = new gnupg();
```

Calling the command prompt this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'gnupg' not found
```

Comment: Gnupg is installed as a php extension on the OS. Is there any way the CLI execution is running on a different environment? Like maybe you are using vagrant for the 'webserver' part but running the CLI command from the host system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php CLI uses other php.ini settings which I was unaware. Activeting extension in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

solved the problem. After this issue I had problem, with creating Laravel classes. It was connected with the old version of Laravel 5. Solution and the related question can be found here:

[Laravel 5: Using Cache:: or DB:: within the Console Kernel's schedule() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746606/laravel-5-using-cache-or-db-within-the-console-kernels-schedule-function)